# Set the value of a JSpinner without triggering it's listener

Tags: java, swing

I've got a GUI in Java that has a JSpinner. It has a change listener. What I'm wondering is whether there is any way of changing the value of the spinner without triggering the change listener. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any code you can attach to your post? Otherwise we can't help you because there are many suggestions..

Comment: remove all change listeners since you don't use them anyway?

Comment: Either you want to get notification about value changes or not. Java make no difference between programmatic and UI changes, so you should do it by yourself. For example you can temporary derigester your listener and register it again, after the value has been changed.

Comment: Possibly important nitpicking: The listener is not really attached to the *spinner*, but to its *model*. And the *spinner itself* is a listener to the model, to be able to update the actual UI when the spinner model value changes. So *not* notifying the listeners would mean that the UI is not updated as well. Whatever you want to achieve, there should be a different solution.

Comment: i think you want to listen **alway** to change events but **react** only in certain cases, right?

Comment: I've already solved the issue another way, but yes, I was mainly wondering if there was a way to either tell from the changeEvent what caused the change, some way of programmatically changing it without triggering the listener or a listener that would react to changes through the UI but not programmatically.